# plugin for emails to prevent spam but also let mailto working?

Tags: plugins, email

I'd like to have the emails displayed on my pages/posts in such a way that they to not be able to be read/used by bots/spammers. So for instance I can use some plugin which replace "@" with "[at]" and so on, but in that case I am no longer able to automatically use mailto, like:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" target="_blank" onclick="window.open('https://mail.google.com/mail/?view=cm&amp;fs=1&amp;tf=1&amp;to=somemail@somedomain.com','Compose new message','width=640,height=480')" rel="noreferrer">somemail@somedomain.com</a>
```

Can you please suggest a plugin which can work for this case? (keep the email address as it's normally displayed but prevent bots to read it?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Spam prevention should be done on the email's servers side, by that I mean you should not disrupt your usability because of spam, instead you should use a proper spam block or filtering service on your email side. For example I have been using Postini for years and have pretty much no spam to contend with.

Another option to prevent really badly written bots is a simple encoded email using ascii or JavaScript, that way the bot reads the source and it is useless but the user is still presented with a valid clickable link,

for example:

```
    **test@example.com**
    //becomes in ASCII

 <a href="mailto:&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#064;&#101;&#120;&#097;&#109;
 &#112;&#108;&#101;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109&#116;&#101;&#115;&#116;&#064;&#101;
 &#120;&#097;&#109;&#112;&#108;&#101;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;"></a>

   //
   //or a javascript example:

<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">



    var first = 'ma';
    var second = 'il';
    var third = 'to:';
    var address = 'test';
    var domain = 'example';
    var ext = 'com'; 
    document.write('<a href="');
    document.write(first+second+third);
    document.write(address);
    document.write('@');
    document.write(domain);
    document.write('.');
    document.write(ext);  
    document.write('">'); 
    document.write('Click Here to Email Me!</a>');

</script>
```

You can find a generator here , http://www.ohlone.edu/org/webcenter/emailencoder.html
or here http://www.wbwip.com/wbw/emailencoder.html and there are some javascript ones out there as well like this jQuery one http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/email-encode

Comment: There's also WP's built in function antispambot(). E.g.; <?php echo antispambot(get_the_author_email()); ?> More on this: http://codex.wordpress.org/Protection_From_Harvesters

Comment: wow did not know that!

Answer (score 0):

There's a core function for that: [wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachment );](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)